# Can I run my web form project from my Android device?

Tags: android, webforms

So I have recently made a web form project with visual studio 2013. I would like to run this project directly from my android device. Is that possible?

Also, I'm a total newb so please use small workd ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Android runs Java, Visual Studio is .Net.
You could invest in Xamarin to build cross platform apps from Visual Studio, but it is expensive.

Comment: I've tried using Xamarin but I have had terrible issues with It. For some reason the desktop icon stops working for Xamarin and when I open it directly I suddenly get tones of errors in my project. Also have had terrible trouble uninstalling and re installing it.

Comment: Maybe give some more details about what your web form project does and how you want to run it from android. But, as it stands, you can't create an Android apk from Visual Studio

Comment: I'm trying to make an application for running table top rpgs (ex. dungeons and dragons).  I only have an android phone to bring with me to my games some I'm stuck with developing for that.

Comment: Either learn Java, or expose your web forms project as a web service and consume it as a website?

Comment: Could u recommend any free service to host my project on? And thanks for the advice

Comment: Do a search, or look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/575016/ASP-NETplusfreepluswebplushostingplussiteplusforpl for ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76834/discussion-between-davesav-and-matt-pruent).